# How to compute paired Cohens'd in gtsummary package?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I cannot find the correct way to write the code within gtsummary package to compute paired cohen's d.

```
time <- rep(c("1", "2"), each = 10)
A <- rep(20:39)
B <- rep(100:119)

df <- data.frame(time = time, A = A, B = B)

library(gtsummary)

 df %>%
  tbl_summary(by = time,
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")) %>%
  add_difference(adj.vars = c(B),
                 list(effectsize::cohens_d(all_continuous() ~ time, ci = 0.95, paired = T)))
```

This gives me error: "cannot use 'paired = TRUE' in formula method."

```
#this is standard cohen's d formula
df %>%
  tbl_summary(by = time,
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")) %>%
  add_difference(adj.vars = c(B),
                 list(all_continuous() ~ "cohens_d"))
```

Which is the correct way to use paired = T in the code?
Thank you!

Comment: Going off of just the error message you got in the first one, you may need to use x= and y= arguments, rather than the formula format. See reference page for that function [here](https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/reference/cohens_d.html)

Comment: Hi! thank you, is it possible to specify multiple variable at once with this solution?

Comment: all_continuous() returns a character vector of columns names, see [here](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/select_helpers.html). So you are welcome to try a character vector for the x= argument, though I'm not positive that will work in this context.